# two different models have the same name in admin page django

Tags: django

I have built a custom user model like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_regular = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phoneNumber = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

I want to create another user type called patient which have similar attributes to the User class.
so I added this to my models.py and inherited from User class:

```
class Patient(User):
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

When I want to check them on the admin page, it depicts both as users, not users and patients.
this is my admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, Patient
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomPatientCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    fieldsets = (
        *UserAdmin.fieldsets,
        (
            'User role',
            {
                'fields': (
                    'is_patient',
                    'is_regular',
                    'phoneNumber',
                    'city',
                )
            }
        )
    )


class CustomPatientAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = Patient
    add_form = CustomPatientCreationForm
    fieldsets = (
        *UserAdmin.fieldsets,
        (
            'User role',
            {
                'fields': (
                    'is_patient',
                    'is_regular',
                    'phoneNumber',
                    'city',
                    'age',
                )
            }
        )
    )


admin.site.register(User,CustomUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Patient,CustomPatientAdmin)
```

as you can see, I have registered both models, but somehow the patient model's name is changed to users.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting `verbose_name` to `Patient` in your `Patient` model.

Comment: Using `verbose_name` is indeed a quick solution to the problem. Keep in mind the Patient model is not completely independent from User. In fact it will have implicit reference to user and every time you create patient an user will be created as well. More on Django model inheritance here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `Meta` class in the patient model. Currently it just inherits the Meta from your user model and hence uses it's `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural`. Try this:

```
class Patient(User):
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        pass
```

You can set the `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` explicitly if needed but if you don't Django would automatically use your model's name.